# chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow redirectURL is undefined

Tags: google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

I'm developing a browser extension. The code below, which uses the `chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow` API, was working on one machine. I tried to load the same code onto another machine using the browser's "Load Unpacked" feature, but now the `redirect` argument of the callback is `undefined`, instead of the expected URL string value. This causes the whole thing to fail. I went back to my original machine and removed and added the extension again using the same "Load Unpacked" feature and now it isn't working on that machine either. There hasn't been any changes to this code or to the server in the meantime. What is going on?

```
authenticateButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const redirectURL = encodeURIComponent(chrome.identity.getRedirectURL());
  const clientId = encodeURIComponent("ff");
  const authURL = `https://linksaver.io/oauth?client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${redirectURL}`;

  return chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow(
    {
      interactive: true,
      url: authURL
    },
    redirect => {
      const parsed = new URL(redirect);
      const token = parsed.searchParams.get("token");
      chrome.storage.local.set({ token }, () => {
        showLogout();
      });
    }
  );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that some javascript had been added to the oauth page which intercepted the request and prevented the redirect response from being received correctly.